# How to prove that this is a zero of the theta function?

Tags: theta-functions

We have the definition $$\vartheta(\tau, z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi i \cdot(n^2 \tau + 2 n z)}$$ and I want to show $\vartheta(\tau, \tfrac{\tau + 1}{2}) = 0$.

Substituting it in I get $$\begin{eqnarray}
\vartheta(\tau, \tfrac{\tau+1}{2})
&=& \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi i \cdot(n^2 \tau + n \tau + n)} \\
&=& \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi i \cdot(n^2 \tau + n \tau)} \\
&=& \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi i \cdot(n^2 + n) \cdot \tau} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

and a hint was given that the summand is invariant under the change $n \mapsto -(n+1)$, indeed
$$(n+1)^2 - n - 1 = n^2 + 2n + 1 - n - 1 = n^2 + n$$ so from this I understand that term $n=0$ equals term $n=-1$, term $n=1$ equals term $n=2$ and we can change the sum to:

$$\vartheta(\tau, \tfrac{\tau+1}{2}) = 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{\pi i \cdot(n^2 + n) \cdot \tau}$$

but I don't see how this is zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get
$$
\vartheta(\tau, \tfrac{\tau+1}{2})
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{\pi i(n^2 \tau + n \tau + n)} =
 \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n e^{\pi i(n^2 +n)\tau} 
$$
and in this sum the $n$ and $-1-n$ terms cancel each other out.

Comment: Thank you so much! because it's $\pi i$ not $2 \pi i$!